# How to get approver's comments by task id in SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to get the Approver's comments for e.g. when Approver approve/reject any task then my form add Approver's comments in History list , but I need the same comments in Designer workflow also to mail to the requester , **that your request is rejected for this Reason**

Any Help??

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this in SharePoint designer.  One approach, assuming you just want the final approval/rejector's comments is to place the target comments into a workflow variable and use that variable in your designer workflow (main process).

To do this first create a string variable, i.e. rejectionReason. Next go to into the approval sub-process (or feedback sub-process whichever you are using), under customization, click 'Change the behavior of a single task'.  Scroll down to "When a Task Completes" - here is where you can capture information from an assigned task.  If you just care about rejection, Place If condition and check for your task outcome, i.e. for "Rejected" or whatever you name your task outcomes.  Within the rejection condition set your variable to this current task's comments.

When the task process ends (based on completion conditions) the workflow will progress and you will have your comments ready in the variable.

Comment: Thanks Kurt! I will try and let you know